# MySQL command SELECT values in column - JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jdbc

I'm using MySQL commands via JDBC (Java) to make changes to my database. I have implemented the following method to return the values of a column. The goal is to have the location in the column (row) correspond with their location in the array (index). This works with String columns, but with numerical columns, the ResultSet seems to place them in ascending order, thus making their positioning in the returned String array not reflect their positioning in the column. 'rs' is a ResultSet reference variable.

```
public String[] getColumnContents(String tableName, String columnName) {
    String sql = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM " + tableName;
    String[] results = new String[SQLManager.getColumnLength(tableName, columnName)];

    try {
       rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

       for (int counter = 0; rs.next(); counter++) {
            results[counter] = rs.getString(columnName);
       }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return results;

}
```

Comment: when you are dealing with numerical columns why are using rs.getString ?

Comment: Because this method is used to return the values of columns of multiple data types.

Comment: You can use getObject() instead

Comment: What exactly does `getColumnLength()` do? The counter in your loop counts the **rows** returned by the query. You cannot know how many rows the ResultSet will return, so I doubt `getColumnLengt()` really calculates the number ofr **rows**. You should use a dynamically adjusting `List` instead of a fixed sized array when dealing with result sets from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as adding an ORDER BY clause to the SQL command. Here's my working method:

```
public String[] getColumnContents(String tableName, String columnName) {
String sql = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM " + tableName + " ORDER BY " + columnName1 + " ASC, " + columnName2 + " ASC";

String[] results = new String[SQLManager.getColumnLength(tableName, columnName)];

try {
    rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

    for (int counter = 0; rs.next(); counter++) {
        results[counter] = rs.getString(columnName);
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return results;

}
```